# Relationship between $vw^{T}$ and $wv^{T}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am solving exercise **1.3.36** from *Linear Algebra* (Fraleigh). It says:

Let $v$ and $w$ be column vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. What is the size of $vw^{T}$? What relationships hold between $vw^{T}$ and $wv^{T}$?

My solution:

Both $v$ and $w$ column vectors have size $n\times 1$.

The size of $w^{T}$ is $1 \times n$.

Now, given that $v$ is and $n \times 1$ column vector and $w^{T}$ is $1 \times n$ row vector, by definition $vw^{T}$ is an $n \times n$ matrix -an square matrix.

Then, the relationship between $vw^{T}$ and $wv^{T}$ is just the product between one column vector of $n$ rows by the transpose of another column vector of $n$ rows forms an square matrix.

Is that right?

Comment: Yes but $vw^\top$ and $wv^\top$ has a deeper relationship than only be both a square matrix.

Comment: There is a very simple relationship between the two. Maybe try calculating them both with, say, $v=(1,2),w=(3,4)$.

Comment: What happens when you transpose $vw^T$?

Comment: They also represent symmetrical matrices.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: $$(vw^T)^T = (w^T)^T v^T = wv^T$$

Comment: Does it another relationship?

Comment: They also represent symmetrical matrices.

Comment: @JohnOrtizOrdoñez No they don't, in general.